# Controlling angles between vectors using sum of subvector angles?

Tags: linear-algebra, euclidean-geometry, inner-product

This is a technical question coming out of my research.

Let $\angle(\cdot, \cdot)$ be the angle ($\in [0, \pi]$) between vectors. Consider two vectors $u, v$ in $\mathbb R^3$. Is it true that 
$$
\angle(u, v) \le \sum_{\Omega} \angle(u_{\Omega}, v_{\Omega})?
$$
Here the $\Omega$ indexes length-two subvectors. My research problem only requires the version when $u, v \in \mathbb R_{++}^3$ (i.e., the positive orthant), but I suspect the general version might hold.

Also, does this generalize to $\mathbb R^n$, i.e., $\mathbb R^3$ is changed to $\mathbb R^n$, but we still only use length-two vectors on the right?

Comment: What is $\mathbb{R}_{++}$?

Comment: @AmirSagiv The positive orthant. Edited, thanks!

Comment: you mean that we choose a coordinate 2-plane $\Omega$ by all 3 possible ways and $u_{\Omega}$ is a projection of $u$ onto $\Omega$?

Comment: @FedorPetrov Exactly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the positive orthant you may use the following argument.

We have $\sin \angle(u,v)=\frac{\|u\times v\|}{\|u\|\cdot \|v\|}$, where $\times$ denotes the vector product. Note that the coordinates of $u\times v$ are exactly $\pm \|u_{\Omega}\times v_{\Omega}\|$. Combined with Pythagoras and obvious inequalities like $\|u_{\Omega}\|\leqslant \|u\|$ we get $\sin^2 \angle(u,v)\leqslant \sum_{\Omega} \sin^2 \angle(u_{\Omega},v_{\Omega})$. Assume that however $\sum \angle(u_{\Omega},v_{\Omega})<\angle (u,v)$. Note that whenever $0\leqslant x,y, x+y\leqslant \pi/2$ we have $\sin^2(x+y)=(\sin x\cos y+\cos x\sin y)^2= \sin^2 x+\sin^2 y+2\sin x\sin y \cos(x+y)\geqslant \sin^2 x+\sin^2 y.$

Applying this twice we get $\sin^2 \sum \angle(u_{\Omega},v_{\Omega})\geqslant \sum \sin^2 \angle(u_{\Omega},v_{\Omega})\geqslant \sin^2 \angle(u,v)$, a contradiction.

ED by Ju: The result can be generalized to $\mathbb R^n_{++}$ using the Lagrange's identity, as discussed in the comments below.

Comment: Very nice! You would make your proof even shorter by avoiding "contradiction" in the reasonning.

Comment: I need the sum to be less than $\pi/2$, without contradiction this is not always so

Comment: @FedorPetrov Many thanks, Fedor! That solves the $\mathbb R^3$ case.

Comment: @FedorPetrov Also I realize the argument can be generalized to $\mathbb R^n$ using [Lagrange's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_identity). This also avoids the difficulty of directly generalizing the cross product.

Comment: @JuSun, If you know how to generalize it, I suggest you add this as an answer to your own question. This way everyone can benefit from it!

Comment: @AmirSagiv essentially the same proof works: the square of the sine does not exceed the sum of squares of the sines by Lagrange identity.